# Minimizing attack surface on fresh 2012 R2

Tags: security, windows-server-2012-r2, internet

I'm in the following situation, i will have a fresh server connected to the internet (if required with a firewall between the net and it simply droping all packets on ports other than the one my application is listening on).

It doesn't require any services / features, there is no third party installation except for my program running on it (console application responding to http requests directly).

Is there anything specifically i should do to reduce the exposed area? This is for a standalone server, no internal network, no domain , no nothing, just needing to be able to launch a console app and remote desktop into it (just me, for administration purposes).

Aside from blocking all ports except those used by my app and RDP at the firewall level is there anything i should change / disable that i may not have thought of or is a fresh install already pretty minimally exposed?

This server's security is critical so feel free to add "paranoid level" suggestions as long as they don't disallow an application to listen & respond to http traffic on a given port

Comment: One suggestion might be to run the Security Configuration Wizard on the server after you have your app installed and running. You may have to tweak the SCW security policy in order for your app to accept network connections properly.

Comment: Don't leave RDP open, much safer to configure an ipsec vpn

Comment: Only open your App port BUT only allow your own IP for RDP. Close everything else.

Comment: @krisFR I'm on a dynamic IP :( i need to get that fixed but in the meantime i don't really have a workaround

Comment: @krisFR Using a VPN sounds even more dangerous, it means trusting whoever hosts the vpn to see everything that comes through, has RPD ever proven to be unsecure?

Comment: @krisFR But was that by exploit or because someone figured out your password? If it's the later i'm not worried, if it's the former that sounds really odd as with RDP's widespread use i'd expect it to be patched within hours of an exploit's discovery.

Comment: @krisFR Can you please show a CVE or similar to back up your claims? I've been working with windows for 15 years and I've never experienced RDP being exploited. There are tons of systems being compromised due to bruteforce attacks (like using the default "Administrator" account instead of creating a new one with a random name and/or using weak passwords).

Comment: https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=rdp%20exploit But ok, i respect your thinking and experience, but will never follow your advice on this specific point...I've deleted everything i posted, don't want to be part of it anymore ;) http://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=rdp+internet

Comment: @krisFR To be fair the first link with a CVE is 1) back from 2012 and 2) only enabled denial of service and not remote access to an unauthorized attacker, i too haven't heard of anything like that and would be very surprized with OVH providing prebuild machines all using the same user WITH remote access enabled and not very long passwords probably all on the same ip range(s), if there had been a major exploit released before it was patched it would have created a massive wave in the dedicated medias.

Comment: `back from 2012` So where are your 15 years experience ? nevermind man, i don't care anymore, i have my own thinkings ;)

Comment: @krisFR You're mixing me with pauska . . .

Comment: @Ronan Thibaudau Yes, we disagree, this is not severe, that's life, i respect all thinkings and believes, those are not mines, that's all :) With all my respect, i leave, you are between good hands ! If you really want an up to date answer (like me) you should ask on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Here's a good resource http://blogs.technet.com/b/secguide/archive/2014/09/04/scm-baselines-for-windows-8-1-ie-11-and-server-2012-r2-are-now-live.aspx

Comment: There have been a number of CVE's with the following link describing the one with the most press. Google search "microsoft remote desktop cve" (without quotes). In high security environments RDP is often encapsulated in SSL or IPsec as a layered approach. https://zeltser.com/remote-desktop-security-risks/

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to convert the server to run Server Core, stripping away most of the GUI. It will lower the attack surface, and as an extra bonus you'll need less patching to stay secure. Not all applications supports this however.

Windows Firewall has gotten really good with the years, and you can create extremely tight rules with the advanced firewall settings. I do **not** believe that leaving RDP open to the wild is any less secure than leaving VPN open to the wild. They are both encrypted connections, and they can both be easily bypassed by brute force attacks.

One way of evading most of RDP bruteforce attacks is to change the RDP listening port in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber
```

Make sure that you add firewall rules to allow the RDP traffic on the custom port before you apply the changes!

I also suggest that you create a new admin account (if you haven't already) with a somewhat random username, use a *very* strong password and disable the built-in "Administrator" account.

Comment: I'm not overly worried about brute force attacks (i can use 100+ length passwords) , server core is an option and my app (single console window) should support it but i'm not sure i'd be able to setup my server quite as securely as i've never used it, i'll keep it in mind however

Comment: +1 for the RDP listening port change.

Comment: I, for one don't think changing RDP worth much. A scan with Nmap should find this port no matter where you put it. Though it take more time which is a plus...

Comment: @EliadTech random brute-force attacks do not first scan all 65 thousand ports to see if RDP is listening on them. Changing the default port does a _lot_ for minimizing the attack surface.